# How can I make jquery wait for one function to finish before executing another to update row colors?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery ui sortable. When the rows are rearranged I want to reset the row colors to zebra striped. This is the code I'm using.

```
function reset_rows() {
 $("#rank tbody tr").removeClass("row1","row2");
 $("#rank tbody tr:even").addClass("row1");
}
$("#rank tbody").sortable({
 update : function() {
  reset_rows();
 }
});
```

The function adds the correct row colors then removes them all immediately. How can I get jquery to remove the row classes first then add back the row1 class to the even rows? It adds the row1 class first regardless of what order I use the functions in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if there's something up with your CSS or some such, because basically that should work. I think I'd do it slightly differently, though:

```
$('tbody').sortable({
  update: function() {
    $('tr:odd').removeClass("even").addClass("odd");
    $('tr:even').removeClass("odd").addClass("even");
  }
});
```

(Obviously you'll want to contain those selectors a bit, I just did everything on my example page.)

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/odaxe4/4)

You don't really need two classes (my apologies if I'm misreading this and you're not actually using two classes), you can just apply a class to (say) the even rows, which makes it simpler:

```
$('tbody').sortable({
  update: function() {
    $('tr:odd').removeClass("even");
    $('tr:even').addClass("even");
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/odaxe4/5)

---

Off-topic, but I assume you're doing this with JavaScript and classes because you have to support browsers that can't do this directly with CSS's `nth-child` pseudo class and such... (Sadly, IE6 is still a reality of life, isn't it? :-) )

Answer (score 0):

try using this syntax

```
$('rank tbody tr:even').addClass(function() {
          $("#rank tbody tr").removeClass("row1","row2");
          return "row1";
        });
```

Comment: Remember that the function you pass to `addClass()` is being called on every `tr:even`. So if there are 20 of them, you're selecting *all* the `"#rank tbody tr"` from the DOM and calling `.removeClass()` 20 times, each time removing any previous `row1` that you returned. So only the last one will still have its `row1` class because the others have been removed several times over. Also, you're not calling `.removeClass()` correctly. It should be `.removeClass('one two')`.